# Heterogenous sharding

Tags: sql, caching, sharding, heterogeneous

Exists:
Several databases on different DBSM(Postgres, Mysql, Oracle, Firebird etc)
Databases have several identical rows (ids, entities names)

The task:
Execute read SQL query on the whole list of databases.

The question:
Is there any known solution? May be there some kind of sql cache database or something like this exists already.

Any suggestions, ideas, keywords?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to join across each database, or just have a means to dynamically connect and query?  What programming language?

Comment: I need join across each database and integrate result in SQL way. So the language is SQL or pl/SQL. If your say about language the such integrator is written i prefer C/C++ but it's not the main matter.

Comment: MS SQL Server has a concept of a linked server I think it is called "database Link" in Oracle.

Comment: It seems the virtuoso can do such things, but it´s proprietary soft. I´ḿ looking for an open source.